# How to write list contents to csv file as a single row

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the following sample list:

```
sample_list = [['test1', 'test2'], ['am', 'cm']]
```

I want to write the above list to `csv` file. I'm using the following code for this:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(sample_list)
f_csv.close()
```

The issue is that when I open `sample.csv` I see that `test1`, `test2` are stored in separate columns, same for `am` , `cm` (stored in next row)

I need output in following form: Each sub-list to be listed in separate row and elements of sub-list in one column.

```
test1,test2
am,cm
```

Please can you help me  in where i'm going wrong.

Comment: What are the values of `test_list` here?

Comment: Test_list is same as that of sample_list

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your list to include the comma `,` as a value ***in the converted string contents***, if the list values can be of type `int`, convert them and then create the strings from the lists:

```
sample_list = [[",".join([str(item) for item in sub])] for sub in sample_list]
```

If we add a number to your original list, so:

```
sample_list = [['test1', 'test2', 392], ['am', 'cm']]
```

After the list comprehension, the list will be of the form:

```
sample_list = [['test1,test2,392'], ['am,cm']]
```

Then, call `writerows()` on this list of lists:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(sample_list)
```

The output in `sample.csv` will be of the form:

```
"test1,test2,392"
"am,cm"
```

---

P.s You don't need to close `f_csv`. Using it with the `with` keyword takes care of that automatically.

Comment: i want that output to be as following: `test1,test2(in one row) am,cm(in second row)`

Comment: Maybe you have some confusion about rows and columns. Your original script outputs `test1, test2` in one row and then `am,cm` in the next row already.

Comment: using my script im getting test1 and test2 in separate columns. I need them in same column separated by ,

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for :)

Comment: if the sample_list has number then this solution fails. My sample list can have any type of value(read from another file)

Answer (score 0):

The following script should produce one column per row:

```
import csv

sample_list = [['test1', 'test2', 1, 2], ['am', 'cm', 3, 4]]

with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv, dialect='excel')
    for sample in sample_list:
        writer.writerow([','.join(map(str, sample))])
```

Which creates a file as follows:

```
"test1,test2,1,2"
"am,cm,3,4"
```

When opened in Excel, this would give one column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MartinEvans this is exactly i needed.

Comment: if the sample_list has number then this solution fails. My sample list can have any type of value(read from another file)